# Analyze Number value in Different Conditions with google cloud platform logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I'm struggling to find out how to use GCP logging to **log a number value for analysis**, I'm looking for a link to a tutorial or something (or a better 3rd party service to do this).

Context: I have a service that I'd like to test different conditions for the function execution time and analyze it with `google-cloud-platform` logging.

Example Log: `{ condition: 1, duration: 1000 }`

**Desire**: Create graph using GCP logs to compare `condition` 1 and 2.

**Is there a tutorial somewhere for this? Or maybe there is a better 3rd party service to use?**

PS: I'm using the [Node google cloud logging client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging) which only talks about text logs.

PSS: I considered doing this in loggly, but ended up getting lost in their documentation and UI.

Comment: I think stackdriver might be what I need, it's not clear from the documentation that this is what I need: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-monitoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tools that you could use to solve this problem. However, you suggest a willingness to use Google Cloud Platform services (e.g. Stackdriver monitoring), so I'll provide some guidance using it.

> **NOTE** Please read around the topic and understand the costs involved with using e.g. Cloud Monitoring before you commit to an approach.

Conceptually, the data you're logging (!) more closely matches a metric. However, this approach would require you to add some form of metric library (see [Open Telemetry: Node.js](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/js/getting_started/nodejs/)) to your code and instrument your code to record the values that interest you.

You could then use e.g. Google Cloud Monitoring to graph your metric.

Since you're already producing a log with the data you wish to analyze, you can use [Log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) to create a metric from your logs. You may be interested in reviewing the content for [distribution metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#distribution-metric).

Once you've a metric (either directly or using logs-based), you can then graph the resulting data in Cloud Monitoring. For logs-based metrics, see the [Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#monitoring) documentation.

For completeness and to provide an alternative approach to producing and analyzing metrics, see the open-source tool, [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io). Using a 3rd-party [Prometheus client library for Node.js](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client), you could instrument you code to produce a metric. You would then configure Prometheus to scrape your app for its metrics and graph the results for you.

Comment: Thank you for your insight DazWilkin! That was quite helpful :)

Comment: You're welcome!